How to set up Workspace Verifications in RCPTT
I want to use workspace validation in RCPTT to see if certain directories and files exist. Here is the process I tried:

You have created a new RCPTT project.

Test case has been created.

You added Verification > Workspace within the test case.



So far, it's gone well, but I got stuck in setting up directories and files.
I want to know how to add and verify directories and files, and how to do it specifically.

I also read the RCPTT document and tried to find other information, but I couldn't find it. An example ECL script or a step-by-step description would be very helpful.

You could create the files and folders you need with the file system manager of the operating system you use (Explorer under Windows) and then record it as a Workspace. So the Workspace you refer to must already contain what you expect.
Or, the easier way is to let your program run in a dedicated workspace and examine its output once finished. If correct, simply attach it as "the reference" Workspace to get verified.
You can remove non-relevant or flaky content with the "Remove" button but there is no way to add anything. Add this point you can not even add files with the file system manager, as the Workspace referred in RCPTT is a "remove-only" snapshot of the content and not a link to the actual folder anymore.
If you removed too much, you need to begin with a new snapshot of the Workspace again.
